# christmas tree stump(java)

Tags: java, drawing, project, division

im a beginner in java and im trying to make rthis very basic program that draw a simple christmas of height 5-40.However, the christmas tree stump is just a *,and I would like it to change depending of wich decade we are in: for example, if the user enter number between 5-9, thestump would be 1 * large and height of 1; if user would enter 10-19,stump would be 3 * large and height of 2;20-29 a stump of 5 * large and height of 4...Basically, increase the stump width by two every decade.Heres my code so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int temp;
    do{
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(in);
        out.print("enter a number ");
        temp = scan.nextInt();

        if(temp >= 5 && temp <= 40){ 
            int x = (temp-1)*2 +1; 
            int y = x/2;  
            int z = 1;  
            for(int i=0; i<temp-1; i++) 
            {
                for(int j=0; j<=y; j++) 
                {
                    out.print(" ");
                }
                for(int k = 0; k<z; k++) 
                {
                    out.print("*");
                }
                out.println(); 
                y--;
                z+=2; 
            }
            for(int i =0; i<=x/2; i++) 
            {
                out.print(" ");
            }
            out.println("*"); 
        }else{
            out.print("please enter a number between 5-40 or enter 0 to quit");
        }
    }while(temp != 0);
}
```

}

Im not quite sur of how to do that.Thank you!

Comment: Java has got integer division, which means that an integer divided by another integer will yield an integer. Using this, you can divide your "temp" with 10 and use the result for your height. 11/10 will be 1 (1.1 rounded down), 8/10 will be 0 (0.8 rounded down).

Comment: Im not quite sure what you mean? im beginning in java so..

Comment: I posted an answer with some code, please comment on that post if you need more clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [integer division](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.2) to increase the height of the stump for every 10:th height of the tree:

```
for(int c = 0; c < 1 + temp/10; c++) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= x / 2; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println("*");
}
```

Comment: well this code part doesnt seem to work with my ''else'' statement; it says I have to delete my else statement; could you paste my code and then paste your part of code where it should be? thanks a lot

Comment: Ok. Can you elaborate on what you want the stump to be like? Also, what have you tried, and why did it fail?

Comment: Basically, stump height would increase by 1 every 5, and the width of it would increase by 2 every decade.Example:5-9 would be 1 * tall, 1* wide---- 10-14 would be 2* tall 3* wide---- 15-19 would be 3 * tall 3* wide---- 20-24 would be 4* tall 4* wide---- 25-29 would be 5* tall 4* wide---- 30-34 would be 6* tall 5* wide---- ... But I dont know how o do that.Thanks